# SSRS - MDX - How to create a field?

Tags: xml, ssrs-2008, reporting-services, mdx

```
SELECT {} ON COLUMNS,
EXCEPT(
        EXCEPT(
            DESCENDANTS([Disposition].[Disposition Hierarchy].[Disposition Eligibility].&[Eligible],,SELF_AND_AFTER)
            ,[Disposition].[Disposition Hierarchy].[Disposition Group].&[Ungrouped Eligible]
              )
        ,[Disposition].[Disposition Hierarchy].[Disposition Code].&[030] 
          ) 
,
EXCEPT(
            DESCENDANTS([Disposition].[Disposition Hierarchy].[Disposition     Master].&[Total],,SELF_AND_AFTER)
            , {DESCENDANTS([Disposition].[Disposition Hierarchy].[Disposition     Eligibility].&[Eligible],,SELF_AND_AFTER)
            , DESCENDANTS([Disposition].[Disposition Hierarchy].[Disposition     Group].&[None],,SELF_AND_AFTER)
            ,[Disposition].[Disposition Hierarchy].[Disposition Group].&    [Duplicate / Recently Contacted]}
        ) 
ON ROWS
FROM CUBE
```

I want to create a field in SSRS so I can use the data to populate a Column in my table. How would I query a new field where Field Source would be in XML format?

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean you want to bring in an additional field, from an XML source, and join  it to your MDX results in a table?

Comment: In SSMS, an example of my output is shown in the image. I would like to create a field in SSRS, of #1 output, that I can use to populate a column on a table in my report. Does that make any sense...it's kind of hard to explain with words?

Comment: No you are not making much sense ... 
Have you heard of SSRS Expressions?

Comment: Yes, I have heard of it. hehe Umm, If I execute the above MDX in SSMS, I would get Rows output and Columns output. In SSRS, when I copy paste the MDX, and go into Fields section, I have Field name and Field Source options when I click on Add > Query Field I can figure out the Field Source for the measure column that you see in SSMS output...but I don't know how to create Field Source for Rows output that you see in SSMS output. I want to create a table with two columns, One showing COLUMNS data and one showing ROWS data.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused. Can you provide two images: one showing the results that your MDX currently displays, and one showing your desired results table with the extra stuff in.

Comment: The 1st column that you see in 2nd screenshot which is grayed out..I want to show that data in a column in a table in SSRS. In Dataset window (when you create a new dataset in SSRS), under "Fields" tab (after "Query" tab), there are two things I need to fill out 1) Field Name and 2) Field Value. What should the field value be if I want to pull that 1st columns data?